# Generated csv file when opened using Excel, doesn't show values within columns

Tags: c#, excel

I'm generating some xlsx files in my application and then i proceed to convert them into .csv files like this:

```
internal static void ConverterExcelParaCSV(FileInfo ArquivoExcel, FileInfo ArquivoCSV)
        {

            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process process in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel"))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }

            Application xlApp = new Application();
            Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Worksheet xlWorkSheet = new Worksheet();
            object misValue = Missing.Value;

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ArquivoExcel.FullName);
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(ArquivoCSV.FullName, XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

        }
```

I've read that if a csv file is opened using Excel, the data will be displayed inside the columns, but they are all inside one cell, separated by commas, like this:

```
VDAL,40,,22018364,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,239,27/03/2019,31/12/9999,,,(some columns are not filled)
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: What language is your Excel in? Some non-English versions expect csv's to be delimited with semicolons (`;`).

Comment: The language is PT-BR

Comment: That may be why, can you change the delimiter when generating the csv?

Comment: I don't think i can...because another system consumes the csv files to upload some data.....

Comment: Try changing the extension of the file to `.txt` and importing it as delimited text

Comment: I've checked some files my friend sent me (csv) and they are separated by semicolons when they are opened using notepad. How can i change the delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your default delimiter to a comma, a semicolon or whatever you discover is being used for a delimiter in the target file.

1) Go to control panel

2) From the Regional and Language Options dialog box select the Regional Options Tab

3) Click Customize or Additional settings

4) Enter a new separator in the List separator box